# Website home page Load Issue

Tags: php, sql, performance

My website home page takes more time to load. when i run my website on,it disformed,images are here and there for some time and then after loading it become ok.

There are three tables which fetches data from database(my sql, php).So i have three select queries with UNION.

What should i do either to keep queries on home page OR i should use ajax jquery to populate it.?

How i can improve speed of app?

I do not need to query again and again in an hour,so what i can do?

One query is here

```
SELECT * FROM ABC
UNION
SELECT * FROM XYZ
```

Comment: Establish whether this is latency or database issue.  Create a cache of the page (ie a straight html version) and serve that up.  Do you then still have the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Measure which part of code is executing for the longest period of time. You can do this by printing HTML comment with timestamp, than go through page code. After that you will know where bottleneck is and which part you need to optimize.

Few general tips:

1. Measure time of sql queries. If it is long make sure that you have proper conditions and indexes
2. Use server-side paging for grids with many records
3. You can use ajax to load few parts of the page in parallel.
4. Caching result of long running queries is good way
5. Caching preprocessed result of query is even better

In some cases the best way is to write something from scratch

Comment: how to measure time of queries? how to cache result/processed result ?

Comment: You can use microtime() function. Subtracting two values will give you execution time. As far as I know php does not have builtin cache mechanism, so to you cache you will need something external (some frameworks have cache functionality)

Comment: @Novakov - use memcache

Comment: @Mayur - I know about it but I never used it.

Comment: @Novakov Well go ahead & use it..!! There are lots of tutorials online .. http://tinyurl.com/7evqujd sud get u started.

Comment: @Mayur I stopped using php few years ago ;)